# Unable to close region in vim syntax file

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a syntax file for a non-standard file extension. An example I am trying to get to work is as follows

```
top {

    num = 1;
    string = hello;
    bool = true;

    contained [
       one;
       two;
       three;
   ];

};
```

I use the following syntax to make my groups:

My vimscript. It does more, most of which works, so I am just putting in some very basic stuff.

```
syntax region top start="{" end="};" fold transparent contains=nest

syntax region nest start="\[" end="];" fold transparent contains=nestedContent contained

syntax match nestedContent '.*;' whitespace contained
```

After all of this I can tell that the "start" in both regions are successful as contained matches (not listed) work starting at the appropriate start, but work below the closing mark. I have looked at all the help docs and several tutorials but I am not sure what I am missing here. Without figuring out how to close regions I am pretty stuck